# Allow Shiny numericInput to depend on another numericInput

Tags: shiny

I am creating a Shiny app where I would like to have the default of a `numericInput` be dependent on another default to a previously defined `numericInput`.

e.g.,

Here I would like the `numericInput` elements of (2) to be the reciprocal of (1), without having to specify values for `value`,`min`,`max`, and `step` beforehand:

```
(1) numericInput("obs1", "Label1", value = 10, min = 10, max = 20, step = 1)

(2) numericInput("obs2", "Label2", value = 1/10, min = 1/10, max = 1/20, step = 1)
```

Above (1) is the previously-defined `numericInput`.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want an `input` object to have *dynamic parameters* you need to use `uiOutput`, so that you can generate them in **runtime** (in `server.R`).

Example: In the first column you can set `min`, `max` and `value`. Modifying any of them renders `obs1` and `obs2` with new parameter values.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  column(6, 
         tags$h2("Set parameters"),
         numericInput("value", "Value", value = 20, min = 10, max = 60, step = 10),
         numericInput("min", "Min", value = 10, min = 0, max = 30, step = 10),
         numericInput("max", "Max", value = 40, min = 40, max = 60, step = 10)
  ),
  column(6,
         uiOutput("ui")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$ui <- renderUI( {
    tagList(
      tags$h2("Numeric inputs that depend on reactive data"),
      numericInput("obs1", "Label1", value = input$value, min = input$min, max = input$max, step = 1),
      numericInput("obs2", "Label2", value = input$value + 5, min = input$min - 5, max = input$max + 5, step = 1)
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Please note that you need to wrap elements in `tagList`, when you want to pass more than one input element to `renderUI`.

Comment: What if, in addition to a user being able to input their own numericInput values, I'd also like to have numericInput values be dependent on those found in an uploaded file? In this case, values to numericInputs will be filled-in automatically by the system. Is the idea the same?

Comment: Yes, the idea is exactly the same